# Dependency Injection: What are advantages of using a framework?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, service-locator

### Introduction and Question

I understand what the [advantages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19203/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-dependency-injection-and-ioc-containers) of dependency injection, e.g. constructor injection or setter injection and that it is one way of doing inversion of control. I also understand that service locators are another way of doing inversion of control - but one that should be avoided. I am following the [terminology of Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#ServiceLocatorVsDependencyInjection).

Dependency injection as a principle can easily done by simply defining an interface having (possibly multiple) implementations for that interface and giving one instance, which adheres to the interface to as an argument to another class/objects's method (e.g. a constructor or a setter or a different method).

I do not see why I should use a dependency injection framework (DIF). **What are the advantages (and disadvantages) of using a dependency injection framework, which is no service locator framework?**

### Details

I [read](https://dzone.com/articles/dont-blame-the-dependency-injection-framework) that some framework allow things to be "registered" - but that sounds awfully close to a framework that implements the service locator pattern, not dependency injection. What's up with that? After reading the answers to [Why are Service Locator frameworks often called Dependency Injection Containers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/415076/why-are-service-locator-frameworks-often-called-dependency-injection-containers), it seems to me that - in fact - DIFs are service locator frameworks and the only part of "dependency injection" is the registration of the services into the framework. **Are dependency injection frameworks secretly implementing the service locator pattern after all?** [One answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/415157/198127) says that there is indeed too little benefit of a DIF if it is not a service locator, that is why such a framework does not exist.

**More Background** (if not important, please ignore it): I am mostly programming in Python. However, I am mostly interested in the general principle.

Comment: Mark Seeman, widely regarded as an expert on DI Containers, provide a pretty good summary of the pros and cons [here](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/).

Comment: I strongly dislike "dependency injection" because I find that it makes it much more difficult to be certain what the source-code will actually *do* when executed.  But maybe that's just me.

Comment: @MikeRobinson: Are you sure you mean the same thing as I do, when I say "dependency injection" and that you do not mean the thing that I call "service locator"?

Comment: Does your question only aim to DI Containers ? Or eventually broaders framework that can do more than being a DI Containers ? (Ex : Java Spring from which you ca use annotation not only for DI but also to manage transaction automatically, role check, url endpoint declaration with automatic parsing of the input request into object...)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It sounds to me that 1) Mark Seeman's "Pure DI"/"Poor man's DI" means my "dependency injection", 2) that his "Explicit register" is the same thing that I called service locator, where you need to explicit register each service - or where you could say that the service gets injected into the framework, and 3) that his "Convention of Configuration" is... well, the non-explicit form of that. Did I get this right?

Comment: I don't know.  Does the terminology really matter all that much?  Isn't the real goal determining why any or all of these techniques are useful or not?  Personally, I like the *idea* of DI containers, especially for complex object graphs, but in practice you're only going to set up those object graphs in an Aggregate Root anyway, so there's always one place where all your configuration goes.  The most interesting thing I've seen done with DI containers is "discovery" of modules that can be loaded dynamically at runtime.

Comment: @Walfrat: I guess both: I am new to the topic, so I am not aware of all those aspects. An explanation of those differences might be helpful. When I wrote up the question I was mostly thinking about the dependency injection which is NOT a service locator pattern. In other words, I was thinking that there are frameworks that help with dependency injection *without* a registry. It seems to me after reading the thing from Mark Seeman and the other answer that I mentioned that there is indeed no such framework, but the frameworks that are out there are actually what I mean with "service locator".

Comment: @RobertHarvey: "Does the terminology really matter all that much?" Yes, otherwise we are not able to communicate as humans ;-). I had enough issues in my job, because we did not realize we talked about different things. "Isn't the real goal determining why any or all of these techniques are useful or not?" ultimately you are right. But if I want to talk with others, we need to speak the same language also. The rest of the things you mentioned sound interesting and I am happy to read more about it if you could provide links.

Comment: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/22795459

Comment: Seeman actually calls it a *composition root:* see https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/

Comment: The primary objection to the Service Locator pattern seems to be that it tightly binds the container to your code, which can be a problem for many DI containers.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27854298/102937). The way you solve this is by introducing an `Interface` or other form of indirection for the DI container; your program then deals with an interface instead of a concrete DI implementation, allowing you to swap the container for any implementation you like.

Comment: The Prism Framework (which I use to build WPF applications) does this two ways: by using an [IContainer interface](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/dependency-injection/add-custom-container.html), and by employing a [Container Locator](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/dependency-injection/container-locator.html) mechanism.

Comment: "I read that some framework allow things to be "registered" - but that sounds awfully close to a framework that implements the service locator pattern" - Here's the difference. A service locator is a global object that you'd refer to from *within* a component (such as a class) to obtain a dependency, so there's no explicit parameter for the dependency, and it's not easy to replace it with something else. A dependency injection container configures dependencies and injects them externally, e.g. through constructor injection; you can easily bypass it (e.g. in tests, you can inject manually).

Answer (score 1):

The magic of DI container is to avoid doing a very tiresome manual binding of all your objects. Binding that will need to be updating every time a single thing change.

Whatever is made of your DI container (service locator pattern inside) is not your problem. What matter to you is that it works and you need to explicitly reference the service locator or whatever he's using inside most of the time (except special cases as always).

for instance in Java/Spring I would have :

```
@Component
public class XX implements IMyInterface{

   @Autowired
   public IMyBean injected;

   @Transactional
   public void save(MyObject toSave){...}
}
```

Here :

- @Component indicate to the framework to register this class, by default it will be instantiate only once and as such it must have no state or one that does not change once initialization is done. In the case of Spring, you can eventually control the scope of the instantiation, for instance you can tied it to the current thread, of the current HTTP user session.
- @Autowired : indicate that I want the DI container to inject a instance that implements the interface IMyBean. If there are more than one candidate i will need to add extra information to help my DI container to resolve it.
- @transactional : here we are outside of just the DI Containers context, here the framework will automatically open a database transaction for me if one is not already active and commit it after the transaciton (or rollback if there is an exception).

As such we can see that :

- I don't need to maintain one big main where I initialized everything by hand. Let alone multiple of them if I have a need for. I might still need a main but it will be lighter.
- By making everything singleton by default, it will avoid multiple instantiation of the same thing if it is not needed
- A framework can do more than just inject dependency, it can even read annotation in order to avoid classic boilerplate code (get a connection from the pool, open transaction, commit/rollback, release the connection), allowing me to focus on what I want to do.
- Instead of making a public class, I could have make it package private, so I would only expose my interface (my API) to the code than need to use implementation of the said interface.
- Standardization : by making every library you might need usable the same way, it's easier to grasp the next dependency you will need to use and that your framework will manage for you.
- You can also have some way to detect new dependencies and integrate them at runtime (for instance if multiple team works on same large project).

Some of the cons when you start are the following :

- Cyclic dependecy will make your code crash at runtime and might be not easy to solve (generally it is a design proble).
- Without a solid grasp of the basics, you will be lost of what is the framework doing for you and why sometimes it behave like it is (for instance, knowing what is a transaction/commit/rollback for relational database). For instance authentication and security isn't an esy topic when you need something solid, so understanding how the framework is doing it for you is also not easy.
- When it does not work for some reason (configuration, dependencies version problem) it might take some effort to resolve.

Comment: I find it fascinating that we've immortalized the Singleton (widely regarded as an anti-pattern) in DI containers, but I agree that having the ability to specify lifetime scope is a very useful feature.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yeah but I’ll never forgive them for cluttering POJOs with annotations.

Comment: This is nice example when framework trying to do too much for you :(. Talking about transactional annotation

Comment: @Fabio their goal seems to be to trick you into using what is effectively a new language. One that specializes in something called vender lock in. I mean, they don’t force you down that path. But they make it awfully easy.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the downsides of singleton when they're not done with DI container is the hard dependencies and hard call to "MyServiceImpl.getInstance()", since the DI do it for you without needing to have direct dependencies, you do not have that downside of the Singleton pattern.

Comment: @candied_orange it's about "standarsing" (making standard ?) your architecture and code. It has a lot of advantage and ofc some inconvenient, like the learning curve which is a bit harder than just the langage. How can a framework be a framework if it doesn't "standardize" the architecture/code it covers ?

Comment: @walfrat the less the code knows about the framework the more flexible the code is. It used to be that spreading knowledge of a design decision everywhere was only acceptable when the decision was choice of programing language. When you do the same with a framework you're effectively inventing a new language to work in. That comes at a cost.

Comment: quite some library have pure code and have a spring integration. This keep it more flexible but there is also an extra cost to make it separate. It does make sense for a library tbh. But for me, considering that I would move from Spring while staying in Java make little sense. I could move to NoSQL, from a Web client to a Desktop Client, but I see extreme little reason to consider that I woulc move from the framework I use. I could ofc take the time to separate like a library, but i'd have a hard time explaining justify that cost to non technicla people that hold the money.